# How to always prompt password for OData feed in Power Query in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, authentication, odata, powerquery

I am connecting to an OData feed which is connecting to SAP. The feed requires authentication for fetching the data.

Now, when I pass the credentials, it is saved and is never asked again.

How to enable password prompting every time the excel is opened.

Comment: Why do you want that behavior? The credential is saved per-user per-machine, so other people won't be able to use your credentials when they open the workbook unless they are logged into your account.

Comment: You have mentioned that credential is saved per user per machine. Does this mean that if I share this excel file (after entering the password in my machine) to anyone else, the receiver has to again enter his / her credential to check / update data from the feed.

If this behavior is not there, then I can't ensure that whoever is opening the excel, gets the data only after entering his / her credential. This is necessary to maintain that only valid users can get access to the data.

Comment: That's correct: if you share your workbook with someone else, they have to enter their own credentials to connect to the data source. However, keep in mind that data filled to the worksheet will still be in the worksheet until they refresh it (the data will not be visible in the queries view).